# Facebook Like button error: Message Failed: This message contains content that has been blocked by our security systems

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I'm developing an JavaScript application. A portion of it contains logic, where I should determine if user liked a certain Facebook page. For that I have inserted the Facebook like button into the HTML page. Here is the HTML source:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
    <html>

        <head>
            <title>Facebook app test</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                FB.init({
                    appId  : '1420154948223014',
                    status : true, 
                    cookie : true, 
                    xfbml  : true  
                });
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/cocacola" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

        </body>

    </html>
```

When the "Like" button clicked things are like in the screenshot http://postimg.org/image/hulovrz5v/.

When I click on the "Error" a pop-up opens with following message:
`Message Failed: This message contains content that has been blocked by our security systems.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This message can appear if you are trying to share something from localhost. If this is not the case you can unblock your website by Facebook using this Link: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/244560538958131